# nginx: serve remote images via https

Tags: php, nginx

Is there a way to have nginx serve a **remote** HTTP image via HTTPS? I'm basically looking for an nginx-only alternative to the below PHP:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']);
```

Comment: Can you explain why you would want this? In what situation are you using this? What is wrong with the php solution?

Comment: our site runs completely in HTTPS while some users post images in HTTP. Serving them via HTTP brings the annoying "some resources are not protected" message. If I could do it entirely in nginx I would save the PHP process.

Comment: plus nginx lets you cache resources via memcached so i'll be only retrieving them via http once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `proxy_pass` directive with variables (`$arg_*` represents GET arguments):

```
location / {
    proxy_pass $arg_url;
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
}
```

- http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass
- http://nginx.org/r/resolver
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables

Please pay attention, that this configuration effectively makes an open relay from your server. So, I do NOT recommend it for any production use.